# pelican taking longer and longer as I write more and more posts.. is it re-making the old posts too?

Tags: python, pelican

Hi I started using [pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com) static site generator, but I noticed, its while making html its taking more and more time as I go on writing more and more posts,

is it re-making the old posts as well ? is their any I can just make html and make only the new post to add to the existing ones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Is it re-making the old posts as well?***

Yes, it does! 
In fact it's said writing the files each time is a lot faster and a lot more reliable than to compare, save and generate hash. From the Pelican FAQ:

> In order to reliably determine whether the HTML output is different
>   before writing it, a large part of the generation environment
>   including the template contexts, imported plugins, etc. would have to
>   be saved and compared, at least in the form of a hash (which would
>   require special handling of unhashable types), because of all the
>   possible combinations of plugins, pagination, etc. which may change in
>   many different ways. This would require a lot more processing time and
>   memory and storage space. Simply writing the files each time is a lot
>   faster and a lot more reliable.

Read *["Why does Pelican always write all HTML files even with content caching enabled?"](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/faq.html#why-does-pelican-always-write-all-html-files-even-with-content-caching-enabled)*

**is their any I can just make html and make only the new post to add to the existing ones ?**

When setting WRITE_SELECTED list on settings you can specify only select content to write to. Thus only those files will be written.
This list can be also specified on the command line using the **--write-selected** option, which accepts a comma-separated list of output file paths. By default this list is empty, so all output is written.

Read: [*"Writing only selected content"*](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/settings.html#writing-only-selected-content)